# PHP file_get_contents not working on CentOS

Tags: php, web-scraping, centos

I am using file_get_contents to scrape a webpage. The code is very simple and works perfectly on windows, mac, and almost all major debian based linux distros. On CentOS the server sends 410 Gone instead.

Running on CentOS 7 64 bit with PHP 7.3

```
<?php

$x = file_get_contents('https://m.apkpure.com/facebook/com.facebook.katana/download'); 

echo $x;
```

On my MacOS
[image: On My Mac]

On CentOS 7
[image: On CentOS]

Both OS' are up to date and are running PHP 7.3

Answer (score 2):

The reason you are getting this error is because you need to pass a user agent (headers) when using https, or the server will reject the request.

To make things easier its better to use cURL, you can see if the function below fixes your issue. The reason it works on your windows and mac is because the server may be assigning a header/useragent to the request and linux is not.

A way to fix this on your linux box is by enabling  `allow_url_fopen` in your php.ini

Try the function below. Without needing to enable `allow_url_fopen`

```
 function scraper($url) {
      $ch = curl_init();
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
      $data = curl_exec($ch);
      curl_close($ch);
      echo $data;
    }

    scraper("https://m.apkpure.com/facebook/com.facebook.katana/download");
```

Comment: this didn't work i tried it the very first time. i don't think this has anything to do with the function name it's centos's default behavior towards this particular site. can you confirm by testing it ?

Comment: I tested the function scraperI posted on top, on a debian distro I was getting the same error as you, and the function with curl and it worked.

Comment: check the title of the source code you received it's the 401 Page bro. file_get_contents stops after status code this one fetches the error page source as well but not the actual page.

Comment: because its pulling where the URL is going, "https://m.apkpure.com/facebook/com.facebook.katana/download" if you visit this URL in the browser it will take you to a 410 - Page Deleted or Gone. So the code is working correctly as its parsing that page.

Comment: but the url responds normally on any ubuntu or mac or even windows as mentioned in the original question. 

https://stackoverflow.com/q/54449110/2651080

Comment: I am on a mac right now, if I copy and paste that url in my brower I get a 410 - Page Deleted or Gone error. So either you have cached data that is making the page show up differently on your windows and mac than on your linux. Because that page in a 410 error page, a operating system you visit it with is not going to make a difference if the page does not exist. Unless you have stored cache data.

Comment: works for me. i have cleared my cache and changed machines multiple times.

Comment: by removing the /download at the end it corrects the url to be found. Also removing the m. makes it load in desktop view better.

Comment: The download part is necessary as it downloads the file. Try using the site once to understand the problem before concluding

Answer (score 0):

Execute this command:

```
sudo setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1
```

Restart web service.